# Отключить проверку сертификата

Tags: c#, wcf

Разместил сервис WCF на удаленном хосте (в данном случае Azure). В проекте не нужна проверка сертификата X.509, поэтому её нужно отключить. В web.config'е прописано:

```xml
    <system.net>
        <settings>
          <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false"/>
        </settings>
    </system.net>
    ...
    <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_Config" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
     </wsDualHttpBinding>
```

Так же проверка отключена на клиенте (CertificateValidator реализован):

```xml
    <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DisableServiceCertificateValidation">
      <clientCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom"
            customCertificateValidatorType="ProjectManagement.CertificateValidator, ProjectManagement"
            revocationMode="NoCheck" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
```

Однако при такой конфигурации подключение к сервису попросту виснет. Что сделано не так?

Comment: В чем проблема добыть валидный смертификат, и не заниматься вот этим вот всем?

Comment: @aepot , не проще отключить проверку, если она не нужна как таковая?

Comment: Это похоже на дыру в безопасности? Вы можете использовать HTTP вместо HTTPS, если вам не нужен защищенный канал, на HTTP проблема решится сама собой, так как там в принципе не используются сертификаты. Но прикрутить нормальный сертификат не так сложно - [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/320918/)

Comment: Тогда не очень понимаю, как сделать это для WSDualHttpBinding. (Схожу с ума от этого уже 3-й день, поэтому буду благодарен, если Вы просто покажете пример= ) )

Comment: wsDualHttpBinding - это двустороннее соединение на основе двух односторонних, соответственно безопасность и сертификаты вам нужно отключать на обоих сторонах.

Comment: ну и попробуйте записать траффик с помощью Fiddler или Wireshark, чтобы понять на каком этапе "затык"

Comment: не забудьте включить и изучить [трассировку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing), там могут попасться полезные сообщения об ошибках

Comment: да, ещё может помочь составление customBinding с нужными вам элементами (и поочередным их выкидыванием)

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, это понятно,что нужно отключить и на клиенте проверку. Вопрос в том, как это сделать. На клиенте отключение сертификата прописано в endpointBehaviors, на сервере указан параметр "<security mode="None"></security>"

Comment: @АлександрПертенава вообще-то настройки биндингов обычно должны на клиенте и на сервере совпадать...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, сейчас и на сервере, и на клиенте установлены:
1) <security mode="None" />
2) <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
Толку нет

Comment: @aepot, при создании сертификата таким образом встаёт проблема добавления DNS-записи в домене. Как это сделать в облачном сервисе - хороший вопрос...

Comment: Оно поддерживает несколько способов ввлидации сайта, не только dns. Будьте внимательны.

Comment: @aepot, извините, но тогда я откровенно не понимаю, какой способ еще доступен кроме как проверки dns-записи...

Comment: [Challenge Types](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/)

Comment: @aepot, так вопрос именно в том, чтобы добавить домен облачной службы в веб-приложение, иначе letsencrypt необходимо, чтобы в веб-приложении был привязан хотя бы 1 пользовательский домен

Comment: Ну без домена совсем, только по айпишнику, конечно ни о каком TLS речи быть не может. Так что вам нужен публичный домен, любой.

Comment: Так сразу и добавил другой домен, но letsencrypt устанавливает сертификаты только на те домены, которые привязаны к web app... Да, обсуждение растянулось, жаль

Comment: Если кто-то может еще помочь - буду очень благодарен!..

Comment: Всё еще актуально!

Answer (score 1):

`<security mode="None">` (Transport и что-то там ещё) это для другого.

Начните не wsDualHttpBinding, а с обычного basicHttpBinding, укажите в baseAdress http а не https:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MEX" name="asdf">
        <endpoint address="фыва" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindings" name="MainEndpoint"
                  contract="asdf" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8021/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MEX" name="asdf">
        <endpoint address="фыва" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindings" name="MainEndpoint"
                  contract="asdf" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8022/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBindings" closeTimeout="00:07:00" openTimeout="00:07:00" receiveTimeout="00:07:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:07:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483646"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MEX">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Да, это работает с basicHttpBinding. Но как решить такую же проблему с wsDualHttpBinding, потому что сервису для работы необходимо именно это подключение?